# UI-Select is not updating the model after a delete

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, ui-select

I have a simple list in `ui-select`, if I choose to delete an item, and load in the `ui-select` the first element available in the list, the model associated don't get updated. Not sure what I am missing !.

Definition of the ui-select:

```
<ui-select on-select="loadSelected($item)" ng-model="selectedDude">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="{{selectedDude.name}}">
      <span> {{selectedDude.name}} </span>
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="d in data | filter: $select.search">
      <span ng-bind-html="d.name  | highlight: $select.search"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

This function is the one I am using for delete:

```
$scope.deleteSelected= function(){
            $scope.data.splice($scope.data.indexOf($scope.selectedDude),1);
            $scope.selectedDude = $scope.data[0];
        };
```

[Check the example in plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/oyBUYY7Dz1W44wRQhjZq) 
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've modified the plunkr for you to get it working. https://plnkr.co/edit/rCKCng6ecXiZ8cNGTBlz?p=preview

First, I added a small utility method in `Array` to remove an item from a list of objects:

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(key, value) {
    var index = -1;
    angular.forEach(this, function(item, i) {
        if (item[key] === value) {
            index = i;
        }
    });

    if (index > -1) {
        this.splice(index, 1);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

There were two problems, the first one was related to how you were removing the `selectedDude` from an array of objects.

```
$scope.data.splice($scope.data.indexOf($scope.selectedDude), 1);
```

Since the dude object reference instance stored in the array might be different from what the scope variable `selectedDude` has. So `splice` might not work properly all the time as you change anything in it.

So we precisly removing it by searching it through the index (using a utility method).

The second problem was of nested child scope. Read [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) for more information. We fixed this problem by creating an object `dataStore` and referencing `selectedDude` from that object like `dataStore.selectedDude` to prevent child inheritence problem in Javascript.